# Rsyslog is losing messages

Tags: rsyslog

I am using `rsyslog v5.8.11`. I found this version number from what `rsyslog` logs on restart.
I am trying to apply rate-limiting in `rsyslog` but it is of no use. I am still losing messages. In the configuration file I put these options to implement rate-limiting

```
$SystemLogRateLimitInterval 5
$SystemLogRateLimitBurst 10000
```

This is of no use as I am still losing messages at the same rate. I even tried to put

```
$SystemLogRateLimitInterval 0
```

This should have stopped the rate-limiting feature of `rsyslog` but instead nothing happened. I am still losing message. These logs are critical to me.
Is there any way possible to stop losing messages in `rsyslog`.

**UPDATE**

On restart i also found this in rsyslog logs.

```
rsyslogd: invalid selector line (port), probably not doing what was intended
```

Is losing logs somehow related to this error.

There are the logs showing that i am losing logs due to rate-limiting.

```
rsyslogd-2177: imuxsock begins to drop messages from pid 25810 due to rate-limiting
rsyslogd-2177: imuxsock lost 103 messages from pid 25810 due to rate-limiting
```

Such type of logs are coming no matter what setting is applied by me. If logs are lost due to UDP will rsyslog log in this manner too?

Comment: These messages that you're losing: are they being delivered by the network, or generated locally? If they're over the network and you're using UDP then there's no guarantee that they'll even get delivered, so it might not be `rsyslog` that is dropping them. You would need to configure the reliable delivery component of `rsyslog` and run `rsyslog` on all your message generators.

Comment: Messages are generated locally. But final storage of these messages are on different server and there i am seeing lost messages in logs. I am updating my original question with the logs which i am getting thus showing me lost messages.

Comment: OK. Same question but asked differently then. How close to the source of the messages are you finding messages are being lost? If messages are being stored on a different server are you delivering messages across the network connection using the reliable delivery feature of `rsyslog`?

Comment: I am reading logs using imuxsock over unix sockets on local machine and then those logs are send to another machine using omrelp.
Also please see my update in question which contain logs showing that logs are lost due to rate limiting.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably using debian wheezy, as rsyslog v5.8.11 is used by this debian release.

Upgrade to debian jeesie or install rsyslog from debian-backports to fix this.

The wheezy rsyslog have a bug that will not disable the rate limit, but the new version will read the config and (finally) disable the rate limit.

Comment: you still need to use the ```$SystemLogRateLimitInterval 0``` or similar, but at least now it should be applied

Answer (score 2):

If you're reading logs from an `imuxsock` input, then rate-limiting is not affected by `$SystemLogRateLimitInterval`.

You have to use:

```
$IMUXSockRateLimitInterval x
$IMUXSockRateLimitBurst y
```